# How to capture different values in the same column with a similar ID into one row with specific column indicators

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I need to capture the yes or no answer to certain question codes into columns that serve as an indicator for each specific question code. The question codes are set values and for the sake of this example can only be 'A', 'B', or 'C'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am looking forward to any answers you SQL gurus can think of!

Example Input Table:

```
    ID  Question Code   YesOrNo
    1         A             Yes
    1         B             No
    1         C             No
    2         A             No
    2         B             Yes
    2         C             Yes
    3         A             No
    3         B             No
    3         C             Yes
```

Desired Table/View:

```
    ID  A_Answer    B_Answer    C_Answer
    1   Yes         No          No
    2   No          Yes         Yes
    3   No          No          Yes
```

To clarify this is in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    A_Answer = MAX(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'A' THEN YesOrNo END),
    B_Answer = MAX(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'B' THEN YesOrNo END),
    C_Answer = MAX(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'C' THEN YesOrNo END)
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Id;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/TAP3665)</kbd>

Comment: This answer worked great! We will see if it holds up for the other fields that I have to do a similar thing with. Thanks!